# Checking if query_string has a value or else redirect it

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am learning .htaccess
My URL string is

```
http://abc.bcd.com/company/abc
```

I do  apply to redirect my page if the company name is abc, xyz etc. and my rewrite rule is

```
RewriteRule ^/company/(.*?)$ /hhhhh/ll/test_page.html?company_letter=$1    [L,PT]
```

Sometimes my url change to

```
http://abc.bcd.com/company/abc?locale=en
```

What will be query string condition to accommodate both the url and should work properly ?

I have tried this but not helping .

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^locale=(.*)$
```

The rewrite condition should help me like

```
if(locale="something")
  /hhhhh/ll/test_page.html?company_letter=abc&locale=something
else
  /hhhhh/ll/test_page.html?company_letter=abc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `QSA` flag in your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?company/(.*)$ /hhhhh/ll/test_page.html?company_letter=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

Answer (score 1):

The query string part of the incoming URL is a very specific thing. First you should know that classical rewriteRules are not managing the query string.

So, for example, you **cannot make a RewriteRule with a check for a query string parameter value**. Query strings parameters could be repeted several times, could appear in any order, and are not url-decoded (the location part of the url is url-decoded when mod_rewrite works on it).

This explains why some RewriteCond are sometimes used on the `%{QUERY_STRING}`, it cannot be done in RewriteRule but could be tested in rewriteCond, with all the previous probelsm ( repetition, order, url-encoding, etc).

But some `rewriteRule` tags can be applied for query string managment. Currently your tags are `[L,PT]`, which also be writtent `[last,passthrough]`.
You can add a `qsappend` or `QSA` tag which explicitly tells mod_rewrite to combine the original query string and the generated one.

So with

```
RewriteRule ^/company/(.*?)$ /hhhhh/ll/test_page.html?company_letter=$1    [last,passthrough,qsappend]
```

This:

```
http://abc.bcd.com/company/abc
```

Will go to

```
/hhhhh/ll/test_page.html?company_letter=abc
```

And this:

```
http://abc.bcd.com/company/abc?locale=en
```

Will go to

```
/hhhhh/ll/test_page.html?company_letter=abc&locale=en
```

Comment: You say

> you cannot make a `RewriteRule` with a check for a query string parameter value

what about something like 

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /(\?|&)param=value(\?|$)/">
RewriteRule...
</If>
```

TBH, I'm not sure that regexp does exactly what I want.